# Pico-8 player and scene

Tags: beginner, lua

I recently started learning Lua by programming games in Pico-8. It's been fun, but it's time to learn some of the more powerful utilities to get things done smarter and with less redundancy.

I'm an absolute beginner trying to form this nested for loop correctly. Any help would be amazing and help me move onto new ideas and concepts.

I can share a link to the full code if needed / permitted.

Here's the code:

```
 function _init()
 mom = {}
 dad = {}
 -- variable to adjust x and y offset for checking solid tiles when
 -- changing the level (default is 0, which aims at level 1)
 levelpixeloffset_x = 0
 levelpixeloffset_y = 0
 --set which scene stage to display / where actors are placed
 scene = {}
 scene.counter = 1
 -- player variables
 player = {}
  player.sprite = 1
  player.speed = 0.8
  player.movingup = false
  player.spritecounterup = 0
  player.movingdown = false
  player.spritecounterdown = 0
  player.movingleft = false
  player.spritecounterleft = 0
  player.movingright = false
  player.spritecounterright = 0
  player.x = 60
  player.y = 74
  player.w = 8
  player.h = 8
 -- island scene campfire variables
 campfire = {}
  campfire.counter = 1
  campfire.sprite = 13
 -- island scene wave variables
 wave = {}
  wave.counter = 1
  wave.sprite = 86
 -- island scene garden variables
 garden = {}
  garden.counter = 1
  garden.sprite = 32
 -- establishes standard tile width and height
 tile_w = 8
 tile_h = 8
end

-- constantly running loop during gameplay
function _update()
 if scene.counter == 1 then
  islandscene()
 end
 if scene.counter == 2 then
  desertscene()
 end
 playermovement()
 --mom_repel()
 --dad_repel()
 --campfire_repel()
 player_repel()
end

-- draws screen
function _draw()
 cls()
 draw_background()
end

-- checks for solid map tiles, the flag1 state of which are referenced
-- in the btn press check in playermovement(). if flag1 is set, sprite
-- map tiles are solid, and the player collides with them by affecting
-- the players response to btn presses. levelpixeloffset_x and
-- levelpixeloffset_y need to be adjusted as appropriate when changing
-- the "level" or where the screen is drawing and the actors are placed
function solid_tile(x,y)
 local tile_x = ((x - (x % 8)) / 8) + levelpixeloffset_x
 local tile_y = ((y - (y % 8)) / 8) + levelpixeloffset_y
 if(fget(mget(tile_x, tile_y), 0)) then
  return true else
     return false
  end
end

-- draws backround of current scene
function draw_background()
 cls()
 if scene.counter == 1 then
-- island scene sprites and map
  map(0,0,0,0)
  spr(player.sprite, player.x, player.y)
  spr(mom.sprite, mom.x, mom.y)
  spr(dad.sprite, dad.x, dad.y)
  spr(garden.sprite, 28, 85)
  spr(garden.sprite, 28, 75)
  spr(campfire.sprite, campfire.x, campfire.y)
  spr(wave.sprite, 8, 8)
  spr(wave.sprite, 16, 16)
  spr(wave.sprite, 40, 8)
  spr(wave.sprite, 80, 0)
  spr(wave.sprite, 96, 8)
  spr(wave.sprite, 112, 16)
  spr(wave.sprite, 0, 112)
  spr(wave.sprite, 8, 120)
  spr(wave.sprite, 24, 120)
  spr(wave.sprite, 104, 120)
  spr(wave.sprite, 112, 112)
  spr(wave.sprite, 120, 64)
  spr(wave.sprite, 0, 72)
  spr(wave.sprite, 0, 48)
 end
 if scene.counter == 2 then
  -- desert scene sprites and map
  map(16,0,0,0)
  spr(player.sprite, player.x, player.y)
  spr(mom.sprite, mom.x, mom.y)
  spr(dad.sprite, dad.x, dad.y)
 end
end

----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
-- player animation and control section-------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------

--manages all player controlled input and responses
function playermovement()
-- push button test - currently used to change camera / scene (use z)
if btnp(4) then
 scene.counter += 1
end
--move left
 if btn(0) then
  --map collision check
    if (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 1)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 2)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 3)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 4)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 5)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 6)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 7)) == false
    then
     player.x -= player.speed
    end
    moveleft()
 end
--move right
 if btn(1) then
    --map collision check
  if(solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y + 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y + 2)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y + 3)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y + 4)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y + 5)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y + 6)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y + 7)) == false
    then
     player.x += player.speed
    end
  moveright()
 end
--move up
 if btn(2) then
    --map collision check
  if(solid_tile(player.x, player.y - 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 1, player.y - 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 2, player.y - 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 3, player.y - 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 4, player.y - 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 5, player.y - 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 6, player.y - 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 7, player.y - 1)) == false
    then
     player.y -= player.speed
    end
    moveup()
 end
--move down
 if btn(3) then
    --map collision check
  if(solid_tile(player.x, player.y + player.h + 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 1, player.y + player.h + 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 2, player.y + player.h + 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 3, player.y + player.h + 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 4, player.y + player.h + 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 5, player.y + player.h + 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 6, player.y + player.h + 1)) == false
    and(solid_tile(player.x + 7, player.y + player.h + 1)) == false
    then
     player.y += player.speed
    end
    movedown()
 end
end

-- animates player while moving up
function moveup()
 player.movingup = true
 player.spritecounterup += 1
 if player.spritecounterup > 0 then
  player.sprite = 4
 end
 if player.spritecounterup > 4 then
  player.sprite = 5
 end
 if player.spritecounterup > 8 then
  player.sprite = 4
 end
 if player.spritecounterup > 12 then
  player.sprite = 6
 end
 if player.spritecounterup > 16 then
  player.spritecounterup = 0
 end
end

-- animates player while moving down
function movedown()
 player.movingdown = true
 player.spritecounterdown += 1
 if player.spritecounterdown > 0 then
  player.sprite = 1
 end
 if player.spritecounterdown > 4 then
  player.sprite = 2
 end
 if player.spritecounterdown > 8 then
  player.sprite = 1
 end
 if player.spritecounterdown > 12 then
  player.sprite = 3
 end
 if player.spritecounterdown > 16 then
  player.spritecounterdown = 0
 end
end

-- animates player while moving left
function moveleft()
 player.movingleft = true
 player.spritecounterleft += 1
 if player.spritecounterleft > 0 then
  player.sprite = 10
 end
 if player.spritecounterleft > 4 then
  player.sprite = 11
 end
 if player.spritecounterleft > 8 then
  player.sprite = 10
 end
 if player.spritecounterleft > 12 then
  player.sprite = 12
 end
 if player.spritecounterleft > 16 then
  player.spritecounterleft = 0
 end
end

-- animates player while moving right
function moveright()
 player.movingright = true
 player.spritecounterright += 1
 if player.spritecounterright > 0 then
  player.sprite = 7
 end
 if player.spritecounterright > 4 then
  player.sprite = 8
 end
 if player.spritecounterright > 8 then
  player.sprite = 7
 end
 if player.spritecounterright > 12 then
  player.sprite = 9
 end
 if player.spritecounterright > 16 then
  player.spritecounterright = 0
 end
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------
--Level information functions----------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
function islandscene()
 if scene.counter == 1 then
  waveshift()
  gardenshift()
  campfireshift()
  -- island scene mom variables
  mom.sprite = 29
  mom.x = 74
  mom.y = 64
  -- island scene dad variables
  dad.sprite = 45
  dad.x = 94
  dad.y = 64
  -- island scene campfire variables
  campfire.x = 100
  campfire.y = 45
 end
end

function desertscene()
 if scene.counter == 2 then
  levelpixeloffset_x = 16
  levelpixeloffset_y = 0
  -- desert scene mom variables
  mom.sprite = 29
  mom.x = 30
  mom.y = 64
  mom.w = 8
  mom.h = 8
  -- desert scene dad variables
  dad.sprite = 45
  dad.x = 39
  dad.y = 64
  dad.w = 8
  dad.h = 8
 end
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
--utility functions--------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------

-- player-repelling force anchored at island scene mom
function mom_repel()
 if (player.x-1) > (mom.x) and (player.x-1) < (mom.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y+1) > (mom.y) and (player.y+1) < (mom.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 2) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 2) < (mom.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 2) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 2) < (mom.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x - 3) > (mom.x) and (player.x - 3) < (mom.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y - 3) > (mom.y) and (player.y - 3) < (mom.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 4) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 4) < (mom.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 4) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 4) < (mom.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 5) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 5) < (mom.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 5) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 5) < (mom.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 6) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 6) < (mom.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 6) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 6) < (mom.y + tile_h) then
  if player.x < mom.x then
   player.x -= 0.55
  end
  if player.x > mom.x then
   player.x += 0.55
  end
  if player.y < mom.y then
   player.y -= 0.55
  end
  if player.y > mom.y then
   player.y += 0.55
  end
 end
end

-- player-repelling force anchored at island scene dad
function dad_repel()
 if (player.x-1) > (dad.x) and (player.x-1) < (dad.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y+1) > (dad.y) and (player.y+1) < (dad.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 2) > (dad.x) and (player.x + 2) < (dad.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 2) > (dad.y) and (player.y + 2) < (dad.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x - 3) > (dad.x) and (player.x - 3) < (dad.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y - 3) > (dad.y) and (player.y - 3) < (dad.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 4) > (dad.x) and (player.x + 4) < (dad.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 4) > (dad.y) and (player.y + 4) < (dad.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 5) > (dad.x) and (player.x + 5) < (dad.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 5) > (dad.y) and (player.y + 5) < (dad.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 6) > (dad.x) and (player.x + 6) < (dad.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 6) > (dad.y) and (player.y + 6) < (dad.y + tile_h) then
  if player.x < dad.x then
   player.x -= 0.55
  end
  if player.x > dad.x then
   player.x += 0.55
  end
  if player.y < dad.y then
  player.y -= 0.55
  end
  if player.y > dad.y then
  player.y += 0.55
  end
 end
end

-- player-repelling force anchored at island scene campfire
function campfire_repel()
 if (player.x-1) > (campfire.x) and (player.x-1) < (campfire.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y+1) > (campfire.y) and (player.y+1) < (campfire.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 2) > (campfire.x) and (player.x + 2) < (campfire.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 2) > (campfire.y) and (player.y + 2) < (campfire.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x - 3) > (campfire.x) and (player.x - 3) < (campfire.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y - 3) > (campfire.y) and (player.y - 3) < (campfire.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 4) > (campfire.x) and (player.x + 4) < (campfire.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 4) > (campfire.y) and (player.y + 4) < (campfire.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 5) > (campfire.x) and (player.x + 5) < (campfire.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 5) > (campfire.y) and (player.y + 5) < (campfire.y + tile_h)
 or (player.x + 6) > (campfire.x) and (player.x + 6) < (campfire.x + tile_w)
 and (player.y + 6) > (campfire.y) and (player.y + 6) < (campfire.y + tile_h) then
  if player.x < campfire.x then
   player.x -= 0.55
  end
  if player.x > campfire.x then
   player.x += 0.55
  end
  if player.y < campfire.y then
   player.y -= 0.55
  end
  if player.y > campfire.y then
   player.y += 0.55
  end
 end
end

-- attempt at transforming existing "repel" forces into single function
-- with "for" loop
-- o = origin of repel force, a = area around origin's x/y coordinates
function player_repel()
 for o in all(mom, dad, campfire) do
  for a = -1,7 do
   if player.x - a > o.x and player.y - a < o.x + o.w
   and player.y - a > o.y and player.y - a < o.y + o.h then
    if player.x < o.x then player.x -= 0.55 end
    if player.x > o.x then player.x += 0.55 end
    if player.y < o.y then player.y -= 0.55 end
    if player.y > o.y then player.y += 0.55 end
   end
  end
 end
end

-- makes island scene campfire shift
function campfireshift()
 campfire.counter += 1
 if campfire.counter > 0 then
  campfire.sprite = 13
 end
 if campfire.counter > 4 then
  campfire.sprite = 14
 end
 if campfire.counter > 6 then
  campfire.sprite = 15
 end
 if campfire.counter > 9 then
  campfire.counter = 0
 end
end

-- makes island scene garden shift
function gardenshift()
 garden.counter += 1
 if garden.counter > 32 then
  garden.sprite = 33
 end
 if garden.counter > 64 then
    garden.counter = 0
 end
 if garden.counter < 1 then
  garden.sprite = 32
 end
end

-- makes island scene waves shift
function waveshift()
 wave.counter += 1
 if wave.counter > 24 then
  wave.sprite = 102
 end
 if wave.counter > 48 then
  wave.counter = 0
 end
 if wave.counter < 1 then
  wave.sprite = 86
 end
end
```

Comment: For us to review it, you need to provide fully working code. Not code to be written for you. Anyways, we don't have enough information on what you would like to do with this code either.  A final tip on formatting is to paste the code, mark it and hit the `{}` button or `Ctrl-K`.

Comment: Does your if statements work, as it is? Especially the long combination of `and` and `or` seems plausible for failure...

Comment: The code runs as is, the only issue is that the attempt to consolidate the "repel" function into a single one doesn't work at all. You'll notice that I'm not currently calling the mom_repel / dad_repel / campfire_repel functions in the interest of trying to get player_repel to function correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify some of the nested "if statements" :

```
if (solid_tile(player.x, player.y)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 1)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 2)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 3)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 4)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 5)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 6)) == false
    and (solid_tile(player.x - 1, player.y + 7)) == false
    then
     player.x -= player.speed
    end
```

you can write something like this:

```
flag = true
for i=0,7,1 do
  if solid_tile(player.x + player.w, player.y + i)) ~= false then
    flag = false
  end
end
if flag then
  player.x += player.speed
end
```

Comment: Good call, please extend answer if you see other improvements to the OPs code. Like better formatting according to standards, or simplify `if` statements, or indentation... :-)

Comment: Thanks, pkisztelinski! I definitely will work on consolidating those nested statements. My current hurdle is working on fixing what is commented as the "attempt at transforming existing "repel" forces into single function". It should work to replace the existing mom/dad/campfire_repel functions, but clearly my for-loop isn't accurate, though it throws no errors.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm not proficient in any way with Lua, but I do know programming in general, so this review is based upon that knowledge. I'm sorry if I say something which is dead wrong when it comes to Lua.

#### Use spaces and indentation to your advantage

Readability of code is crucial in any language. Even if the language it self doesn't require a fixed indentation (or braces), using indentation will help readability which in turn helps understanding and maintaining the code.

So instead of:

```
function solid_tile(x,y)
 local tile_x = ((x - (x % 8)) / 8) + levelpixeloffset_x
 local tile_y = ((y - (y % 8)) / 8) + levelpixeloffset_y
 if(fget(mget(tile_x, tile_y), 0)) then
  return true else
     return false
  end
end
```

Use this variant:

```
function solid_tile(x,y)
  local tile_x = ((x - (x % 8)) / 8) + levelpixeloffset_x
  local tile_y = ((y - (y % 8)) / 8) + levelpixeloffset_y

  if (fget(mget(tile_x, tile_y), 0))
  then
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

#### Simplify `if .. return` statements

Carrying on simplifying the above statement, you could and should write:

```
function solid_tile(x,y)
  local tile_x = ((x - (x % 8)) / 8) + levelpixeloffset_x
  local tile_y = ((y - (y % 8)) / 8) + levelpixeloffset_y

  return (fget(mget(tile_x, tile_y), 0))
end
```

Possibly without the parentheses around `fget`. No need to do an `if`, and then repeat the output of the condition in the `return` statement. And in the calculation of `tile_x` couldn't it be just: `(x / 8) + levelpixeloffset_x`?

#### Is Lua very fond of globals?

In your `_init` function you initialize the `player`, `campfire`, and so on. All of these seem to be global variables, so I'm guessing Lua is rather fond of globals.

To help this look a little tidier, though, I would consider adding `_init_player`, `_init_campfire`, and so on methods, to help keep the base `_init` function simpler and more understandable.

#### Simplify your `if` statements

You have quite a few `if` statements testing for `some_variable` plus 0 through 7 (or similar). This can be checked either using `for` loops like suggested by pkisztelinski in his answer.

Or since it seems like you're mostly comparing towards an 8 bit (or pixel) values, you could divide your coordinates by 8, and see if the thingy you compare towards is equal.

Another option is to check the absolute distance towards the target. Instead of testing all variants of `player.x` vs `dad.x + tile_w`. Check the (absolute?) value of `dad.x - player.x`. If less than a given limit, they are too close...

#### If you still need multiple conditions, group them

This looks ugly and is confusing, even though Lua has proper precedence of `and` and `or` which seemingly makes it work:

> ```
> function mom_repel()
>  if (player.x-1) > (mom.x) and (player.x-1) < (mom.x + tile_w)
>  and (player.y+1) > (mom.y) and (player.y+1) < (mom.y + tile_h)
>  or (player.x + 2) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 2) < (mom.x + tile_w)
>  and (player.y + 2) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 2) < (mom.y + tile_h)
>  or (player.x - 3) > (mom.x) and (player.x - 3) < (mom.x + tile_w)
>  and (player.y - 3) > (mom.y) and (player.y - 3) < (mom.y + tile_h)
>  or (player.x + 4) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 4) < (mom.x + tile_w)
>  and (player.y + 4) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 4) < (mom.y + tile_h)
>  or (player.x + 5) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 5) < (mom.x + tile_w)
>  and (player.y + 5) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 5) < (mom.y + tile_h)
>  or (player.x + 6) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 6) < (mom.x + tile_w)
>  and (player.y + 6) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 6) < (mom.y + tile_h) then
> ```

Even though not needed I would consider using parentheses, or at least space the condition out so that it is possible to see the connection. Possibly something like this:

```
function mom_repel()
  if    (player.x-1) > (mom.x) and (player.x-1) < (mom.x + tile_w) and 
        (player.y+1) > (mom.y) and (player.y+1) < (mom.y + tile_h)
     or (player.x + 2) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 2) < (mom.x + tile_w) and 
        (player.y + 2) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 2) < (mom.y + tile_h)
     or (player.x - 3) > (mom.x) and (player.x - 3) < (mom.x + tile_w) and 
        (player.y - 3) > (mom.y) and (player.y - 3) < (mom.y + tile_h)
     or 
        (player.x + 4) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 4) < (mom.x + tile_w) and 
        (player.y + 4) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 4) < (mom.y + tile_h)
     or 
        (player.x + 5) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 5) < (mom.x + tile_w) and
        (player.y + 5) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 5) < (mom.y + tile_h)
     or 
        (player.x + 6) > (mom.x) and (player.x + 6) < (mom.x + tile_w) and
        (player.y + 6) > (mom.y) and (player.y + 6) < (mom.y + tile_h) 
  then
```

You can choose between having `or` on separate lines or not, but I reckon you see how much easier it is too read this last example, compared to your original code.

#### In general, when you see repeated `if` statements consider simplifications

In `moveleft`, `moveup`, `moveright` and `moveup` you do exactly the same:

- if `counter > 0` or `counter > 8` use the `base sprite`
- if `counter > 4` use `base sprite + 1`
- if `counter > 12` use `base sprite + 2`
- Reset `counter` if larger than 16

This can be simplified using a helper function:

```
function sprite_offset(counter)

  if counter > 4 and counter <= 8 then
     return 1
  end

  if counter > 12 then
     return 2 
  end

  return 0
end


function moveright()
  player.movingright = true
  player.spritecounteright += 1
  player.sprite = 7 + sprite_offset(player.spritecounteright)

  if player.spritecounteright > 16 then
    player.spritecounteright = 0
  end
end
```

#### And finally, the nested for loop

It seems like one trick to be able to loop over the variables `mom`, `dad` and `campfire` in one go, is to add references to this into another table, and then use `ipairs`. Since we don't really care about the index part of this we can write something like the following:

```
function player_repel()
  for _, entity in ipairs({dad, mom, campfire}) do 
    for a = -1, 7 do
       -- work your magic with player.x > entity.x, and so on
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You are all truly gifted and experienced people, and holroy:

Thank you for taking the time to give such an in-depth answer. I will take some time to dive into this and refine what I've got. Thank you so much!